# Repeater Controls' ItemDataBound - Handle Inline or Codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

Are there any differences between coding row-specific stuff inline within the repeater's template and doing so in the codebehind file in ItemDataBound?

EDIT: Re: differences - I think we're all agreed it makes for markup that's nasty to read/maintain :) I was thinking of performance benefits.

Comment: Define difference. There are differences in readability,maintainability and extensibility. Depends on how you assigned your priorities.

Comment: Updated to clarify what I was getting at with 'differences'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually try to strike a balance between inline code and code-behind code. Any simple processing (1 liners), I put them in the ASPX page. Usually this consists of simple formatting stuff. Anything that requires logic goes in my code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

there are some things you just can't do inline, like binding an inner repeater.